# SDK manager Android 2.2

Tags: android-sdk, android

Я устанавливал пакеты `Android 2.1`, `Android 2.2`, `Android 4.0.3`, но, кроме 2.1 и 4.0.3,  ничего не видит. В чём проблема может быть? Мне нужно создать проект для Android 2.2.

Comment: Ну и в чём проблема? Измените манифест, да попробуйте.

Comment: Изменял, всё равно, всё также, в AVD в списке тоже не показывает Android 2.2.

Comment: А, вы про список устанавливаемых пакетов в эклипс, да, нету 2.2

Comment: Я не понял что вы хотели сказать.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вопрос немного туманный. Непонятно, что и куда вы устанавливали. Сначала убедитесь, что действительно установили нужные пакеты для 2.2.

[image]

Если это так, то останется просто выбрать цель для сборки.

[image]

Comment: уже решил проблему